# Как загрузить с ПК на сайт необходимый файл

Tags: python-3.x, сервер, сеть

На определенный сайт необходимо загружать файлы с ПК.(через это окно)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал реализовать с помощью имитации нажатия клавиш (pynput и pyautogui), но работает частично. Сам бот находится на отдельном инстансе и когда я подключаюсь к нему и слежу за выполнением программы, то все необходимые символы печатаются, если отключаюсь от инстанса, то программа перестает работать и застревает именно на моменте ввода символов. Можно ли это реализовать без имитации нажатий клавиш или как пофиксить баг с печатанием символов?

Comment: Может, напрямую отправить `POST`-запрос?

Comment: Дайте пример кода, где реализуется выгрузка файла.

Comment: from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key


keyboard = Controller()

browser = Chrome('path/to/webdriver')

browser.get(site_url)

Сначала происходит нажатие на кнопку, чтобы открылось окно:

while True:
 
 try:
  
  browser.find_element_by_id('button').click()
 
 except NoSuchElementException:
  
  continue
 
 else:
  
  break

Далее открывается окно, и бот вводит название файла:

keyboard.type(name_of_file)

keyboard.press(Key.enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно.

- Перебираешь окна через [`EnumWindows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows).
- Находишь у окна текстовое поле, делаешь [`SendMessage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) c [`WM_SETTEXT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settext) и устанавливаешь желаемый текст.
- Самому окну (не кнопке) шлёшь `IDOK` чтобы подтвердить выбор [закрыв окно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/closing-the-dialog-box?view=vs-2019).

Это всё winapi.

Spy++ из Visual Studio поможет узнать классы окон и другую полезную информацию.

Comment: Можете прислать некоторую документацию/литературу по этому вопросу. Я гуглил, нашел много чего, но раньше никогда не работал с winapi, и не могу понять, какя информация мне нужна, а какая нет

Comment: @Иван, дополнил ответ.